# Creating a bibliography on TexMaker

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I have always manually created a bibliography for any of my documents. However, for my masters thesis, I have many references. Someone had suggested that I make a bibliography database so that I can use for future writings. I have created a `.bib`file using JabRef. I want to know how do I use this file in TexMaker. I installed the package `biblatex` as suggested on a site but I'm not sure of the next steps to produce a bibliography on my document. If someone could outline the steps required, it will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will have to run Biber on your document. See [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/) for explanations and [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/) for help on how to run Biber in your editor. You might also want to read [biblatex in a nutshell (for beginners)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13509/) and some of the linked introductions there, http://dag.at.ifi.uio.no/public/doc/biblatex-guide.pdf, https://github.com/PaulStanley/biblatex-tutorial/releases

Comment: Is your problem related to how to use `biber` from within TeXmaker, or how to code to obtain a bibliography?

Comment: @Bernard, I have manage to setup TeXmaker to use 'biber' and used the quick build functionality to compile the file correctly. I've tried this with the example `biblatex-examples.bib` and it works correctly. However, when I use my `.bib` file it gives me the error that file cannot be found.

Comment: Is your .bib file in the same directory as your main file?

Comment: @Bernard, Thank you. That seems to have been my problem and has been rectified

Comment: @Bernard, how do I italicize each of the titles in my references. `biblatex` only puts them in quotation marks

Comment: The question about italicising titles is a new one. Please ask it as a new question with a proper [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864).

Comment: Any news here? What should we do about this question?